# HTML5 folder drag and drop but single file selection on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have a drag & drop zone on my web application. The drag & drop zone accepts folders

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" webkitdirectory mozdirectory />
```

I can easily drag and drop folders, a selection of folders, single files and a selection of files. Everything works as expected.

When I click on the drag & drop zone I get the standard Windows modal popup asking me to select a folder, not single files.

What I'd like to have is: when I click on the drag and drop zone I want to see the normal Windows file selection modal, not the folder one

couldn't find any solution for it, is it even possible?

Comment: why are you using `webkitdirectory mozdirectory`

Comment: @VipinKumar please tell me the best approach, I'm open for better solutions!

Comment: Please provide working fiddler/plunker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what `webkitDirectory` does, it limits your `INPUT` to accept only FOLDERS:

https://wicg.github.io/entries-api/#dom-htmlinputelement-webkitdirectory

> The webkitdirectory attribute is a boolean attribute that indicates
>   whether the user is to be allowed to select a directory rather than a
>   file or files.

To support file selection and drag&drop of either files or folder, you'll need to change your approach, you need a drag&drop zone:

https://jsfiddle.net/atfLe15b/

Example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem/webkitGetAsEntry.